# What is the origin of images in design of scifi.se (icons, sprites, logo)?

Tags: discussion, design

I found where [accepted answer image](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1089/20853) comes from, but coundn't find the same information about other images.

[image: sprites]

Answer (score 1):

Some information can be found in original questions about design

- [What should our logo and design look like once we are no longer in beta?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/554/what-should-our-logo-and-design-look-like-once-we-are-no-longer-in-beta)
- [Design for Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/976/design-for-science-fiction-fantasy)

Particulary,

- Badges are resembling the shape of [Star Wars Rebel Alliance insignia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Alliance_Starbird).
- [Header image](http://cdn.sstatic.net/scifimeta/img/bg-header.jpg?v=629272615c60) is the rune circle around the female warrior's silhouette.